# How to replace values in a pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Here's the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lMZr.jpg)

In above data frame, how can I replace a values in 'user_id' column from "Запись пользователя № — user_974" to just "user_974" and instead of '#error' just put blank space '' there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.
let 'df' be the name of you data set

```
l = []
for i in df['user_id']:
    l.append(i[-8:])
df['user_id'] = l
```

Comment: and what about the '#error'? how can i replace that one with just a blank space('') ?